# Parsing xml in clojure with arbitrary tags using clj-xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, clojure

I'm trying to parse some xml using clj-xpath, and basically I want to make a function that looks like this

```
(map
         (fn [item]
           {:title ($x:text "./title" item)
            :url  ($x:text "./url" item)})
         (take 5
               ($x "/search/events/event" (xmldoc))))
```

But with arbitrary tags.
So far, I have this

```
ns mashup-dsl.datamodel
(:use
    [clj-xpath.core])
(def data-url "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?  app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=Belgrade&date=Future")

(def events-xml
 (fn [] (slurp data-url)))

(def xmldoc
  (fn [] (xml->doc (events-xml))))

(def item (take 5 ($x "/search/events/event" (xmldoc))))

(defn create-xpath [tag] (str "./" tag))

(def tags ["title" "url"])

(defn parse [item]
    (doseq [tag tags])(into {} (keyword tag) ($x:text (create-xpath tag) item)))
```

But I'm getting this error, TransformerException Extra illegal tokens: '$', 'tag', '@', '64516c52'  org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error (XPathParser.java:610). So the problem is in parse function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to extract first 5 titles:

```
user=> (map #($x:text "./title" %) (take 5 ($x "//event" (xmldoc))))
("9th International Belgrade Early Music Festival" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\"" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\"" "ICTM Study Group on Music and Dance in Southeastern Europe Conference" "New Belgrade Opera, Madlenianum Opera-Theatre, New Trinity Baroque; Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'incoronazione di Poppea\"")
```

It your example `doseq` inproperly closed and you need to complile expression to use against `xml->doc` result.

You can create a helper function that will return function to extract text from tag:

```
(defn tag-fn [tag] (partial $x:text tag))
```

Now, you can generate functions for "title" and "url":

```
user=> (tag-fn "title")
#<core$partial$fn__4190 clojure.core$partial$fn__4190@71cc2b7a>
```

and

```
user=> (map (tag-fn "title") (take 5 ($x "//event" (xmldoc))))
("9th International Belgrade Early Music Festival" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\"" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\"" "ICTM Study Group on Music and Dance in Southeastern Europe Conference" "New Belgrade Opera, Madlenianum Opera-Theatre, New Trinity Baroque; Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'incoronazione di Poppea\"")
```

or url and title:

```
user=> (map (juxt (tag-fn "url") (tag-fn "title")) (take 2 ($x "//event" (xmldoc))))
(["http://eventful.com/belgrade/events/9th-international-belgrade-/E0-001-064654999-7@2014061420?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "9th International Belgrade Early Music Festival"] ["http://eventful.com/belgrade/events/belgrade-baroque-academy-mijanovic-gosta-9th-belg-/E0-001-059734872-8?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\""])
```

or both url and title:

```
user=> (map (apply juxt (map tag-fn ["url" "title"])) (take 2 ($x "//event" (xmldoc))))
(["http://eventful.com/belgrade/events/9th-international-belgrade-/E0-001-064654999-7@2014061420?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "9th International Belgrade Early Music Festival"] ["http://eventful.com/belgrade/events/belgrade-baroque-academy-mijanovic-gosta-9th-belg-/E0-001-059734871-9?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic" "Belgrade Baroque Academy, Mijanovic, Gosta / 9th Belgrade Early Music Festival / Monteverdi: \"L'Incoronazione di Poppea\""])
```

Comment: ,yes, I see now that I accidentally closed parent on doseq. However, still the same error. And I see that your answer gives appropriate  result, but I need a function that I will pass some tags, to get results.

Comment: excellent, I would just add at the end this (def ks [:url :title])
(defn parse[]
(map #(zipmap ks %) (map (juxt (tag-fn "url") (tag-fn "title")) (take 2 ($x "//event" (xmldoc)))))) that makes a map of tags as keys and values.

Comment: you can use `into` and simplify to: `(map (fn [event] (into {} (map #(vector % ((tag-fn %) event)) tags))) (take 2 ($x "//event" (xmldoc))))`     
`({"title" "9th International Belgrade Early Music Festival",
  "url"
  "http://eventful.com/belgrade/events/9th-international-belgrade-/E0-001-064654999-7@2014061420?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic"}
......`

Comment: yes, but i thought that keyword style is more appropriate, hence the ks structure. but this is also excellent solution, thank you.

Comment: you are right, I would prefer keyword. My point was it can be simplified.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest form would be:

```
  (def url 
      (str 
          "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?"
          "app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&"
          "keywords=music&"
          "location=Tokyo&"
          "date=Future"))
  (def xml (slurp url))
  (def event-titles (map #($x:text "./title" %) ($x "//event" xml)))
```

And the printout of event-titles would be:

> ("FLOPPY 10th Anniversary 「This is computer music」" "IN BUSINESS"
>   "UNIT 10th Anniversary Erection" "In The Mix at 0" "\" 20140530 - Sick
>   Team Release Party \"" "Fanfare Ciocarlia @ World Beat Festival"
>   "Fanfare Ciocarlia @ Musashino Hall" "DBS presents PINCH Birthday
>   Bash!!!" "BLUES SISTERS (from RESPECT)" "UNIST 2nd
>   Album「Acoustic」リリースパーティー 「リリースしちゃってウカれNight(ドヤッ)☆」")

**EDIT**
For a versatile function, you could define:

```
(defn search-for [tag local-path]
  (map #($x:text (str (local-path) %) ($x (str "//" tag) *xml*)))
```

and use it like:

```
 (search-for "event" "@id")
```

or

```
 (search-for "event" "./title")
```

or

```
 (search-for "image" "./url")
```

Comment: I see that this gives appropriate result, but how do I create a function that creates this kind of result for arbitrary tags.